# Rails console doesn't work after update RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb, rails-console, ruby-on-rails-6.1, ruby-3

After update rails to 6.1.4 version and ruby to 3.0.0 and update my Ruby on Rails APP I cant start the rails console either IRB and it doesn't show any error.

Tests performed

1. I have installed the IRB version 1.3.5 after uninstall the 1.3.6 default version. (Doesnt work)
2. Quit gem spring, stop spring service, uninstall spring gem and run bundle install again (Doesnt work)

INFO
CENTOS 7

[image: Info about application's environment]

After run `rails console` it stuck
[image]

Comment: try this: `spring stop` then `rails c`

Comment: I tried that even I uninstalled the gem but It doesn't work for me